# App does not have a new content rating- Unable to upload APK

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play

I am continuously receiving following error message while trying to upload apk in android market via Jenkins. Any thought?

```
Applying changes to Google Play...
Upload failed: This app does not have a new content rating that needs to be set in the Google Play Developer Console.
- No changes have been applied to the Google Play account
Build step 'Upload Android APK to Google Play' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine the error is to do with Google's change to how apps are rated on the Play Store. [This documentation should help you](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en), I think all you need to do is log into the developer console and set a rating for your app.

> Beginning May 5, 2015, all new apps and updates to existing apps will need to have a completed content rating questionnaire before they can be published.
>
> As a Google Play Developer, your compliance and participation with the new app ratings system is required under the Google Play Developer Distribution Agreement. Apps that aren’t rated using the new rating system may be removed from the Play Store.